# Getting ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE in browser while downloading a resource using a link that is present in an email

Tags: java, spring, nginx, download

I am having a API(https://xyz-abc.com/api/signed/resource/get?signedKey=234e23423) for downloading a resource(xlsx, pdf) file. There is an email sent to the user which has a link to download the resource. This link is given href as the API url i.e. https://xyz-abc.com/api/signed/resource/get?signedKey=234e23423

When user clicks on this link from their email, a new tab is opened and that API is called. The file gets downloaded into the user's browser as an attachment. But sometimes the new tab that is opened is not getting closed and in that browser tab the user is shown following message -

```
This site can’t be reached

The web page at https://xyz-abc.com/api/signed/resource/get?signedKey=234e23423 might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE
```

Why this error is shown in the browser and that too in some of the cases. When user again clicks on the same URL then the tab is getting closed automatically and the file is getting downloaded.

I am using nginx and java spring controllers at the backend.

Update 1 - Adding the network tab screenshot -

[image]

Comment: Without seeing the code that serves the file, the network traffic associated with the download request and specific diagnostics about the browser and network connection on the client's side, it's going to be nearly impossible to answer this. The URL of the web resource is very unlikely to be the root cause of your problem in and of itself.

Comment: The information you provvided are limited but nginx can be used as  load balancer. If nginx relies on different instances and your backend is statefull for example signedKey=234e23423 is recoganized only by a specific instance then the page is opened only if nginx points to the right instance that generated the email. If it is the case a suggest to rewrite the back-end i.e. persist the file on the file system and let all beckend instances to generate the response,

Comment: @kolossus I have attached the screenshot of the network tab. You can get the details about the request & response headers from the screenshot. Hope it will help to diagnose the problem further.

Comment: @RobertoPetrilli I have attached the screenshot of the network tab using which you can get the details of the request and response headers. The backend is stateless.